# Timing sprite sheet animations through functions with Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've been working on my first game the last couple of days and I just successfully got the animations sort of working for jumping and running.

Before I go any further I'm trying to clean up my code. I noticed that most other experienced users code is pretty much 90% in functions so naturally I was trying to emulate that (maybe a folly, since I don't know what I'm doing).

An issue I've stumbled upon is that the interval timing methods that worked in an open ended code is no longer work in when separated into functions. On one hand I like the organization of separate functions this sort of feels like it's even more complicated than before.

Here is my clean functions pertaining to moving and pulling the sprite. I'm not sure if I posted all relevant information so please let me know if I can provide anything else:

```
## CREATES SPRITESHEET VARIABLE
def player(spritesheet,moveInput):
    marine = []
    for nbr in range(0,5,1):
       marine.append(spritesheet.subsurface(64*(nbr),64,64,64))

    for nbr in range(5,7,1):
       marine.append(spritesheet.subsurface(64*(nbr-5),0,64,64))

    for nbr in range(7,8,1):
       marine.append(spritesheet.subsurface(64*(nbr-5),0,64,64))

    return marine

## FIGURES OUT WHERE PLAYER WANTS TO MOVE
def playermove():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            mainloop = False # pygame window closed by user
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                mainloop = False # user pressed ESC
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:    
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                moveInput[0] = True;
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                moveInput[1] = True;
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                moveInput[2] = True;
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                moveInput[0] = False;
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                moveInput[1] = False;
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                moveInput[2] = False;

    return moveInput

## RETURNS FRAME FROM SPRITE LIST
def aniframe(moveInput,cycletime):
    interval = .25
    frame = 0
    if not moveInput[0] and not moveInput[1]:
        if cycletime > interval:
            frame = 5
            frame += 1
            cycletime = 0
            if frame > 6:
                frame = 5

    if moveInput[0]:
        if cycletime > interval:
            frame += 1
            cycletime = 0
            if frame > 4:
                frame = 0

    if moveInput[1]:
        if cycletime > interval:
            frame += 1
            cycletime = 0
            if frame > 4:
                frame = 0
    return frame

playersprite = player(spritesheet,moveInput)


screen.blit(playersprite[aniframe(moveInput,cycletime)], (x,y))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to blame this on cycletime. You're modifying it in aniframe(), but your changes will not leave the function, as numbers are passed by value, not reference. You need to return it as well. eg, return frame, cycletime, then outside the function, have frame, cycletime = aniframe(moveInput,cycletime)